# openwhisk cluster setup and load balancing

Tags: openwhisk

I am able to run openwhisk in my local dev machine. I like to extend this to production environment. Is there any concept of openwhisk cluster?. I am not able to find good documentation on this. How auto-load balancing is achieved, etcc..

Answer (score 0):

OpenWhisk is deployed via ansible and as such can be distributed across multiple VMs in a straightforward way.

Check the [README on distributed deployments](https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/blob/master/ansible/README_DISTRIBUTED.md) for further information and guidance.

Comment: Thanks. Just curious to know  how to invoke actions on different VM's. Also like to know what advantage  do we get when we deploy it in Mesos cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Openwhisk will use ansible to deploy the openwhisk
I followed the follwoing way for my distributed setup

1. First ensure ssh passwrod less connectivity to all the servers
2. git clone https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk.git
3. Add the remote_user and private_key_file values to the defaults section of

   the ansible.cfg file. The remote_user value sets the default ssh user. The 
   private_key_file is required when using a private key that is not in the 
   default ~/.ssh folder
   [defaults]
   remote_user = ubuntu
   private_key_file=/path/to/file.pem
4. Go to tools/ubuntu-setup run all.sh to install all the required softwares.
5. Now modify the inventory files(hosts) for your first node. this can become your bootstrapper VM
6. Check if you are able to ping the hosts : ansible all -i environments/distributed/hosts -m ping
7. if ping is fine run the next commad to generate the config files: ansible-playbook -i environments/distributed/hosts setup.yml
8. For installing the pre requisites: ansible-playbook -i environments/distributed prereq_build.yml
9. Deploy registry: ansible-playbook -i environments/distributed registry.yml
10. Go to openwhisk home run the following command to build the Openwhisk
    ./gradlew distDocker -PdockerHost=:4243 -PdockerRegistry=:5000
11. Once the build is successful run the following commands from the **ansible** folder

    12. ansible-playbook -i environments/distributed/hosts couchdb.yml
        ansible-playbook -i environments/distributed/hosts initdb.yml
        ansible-playbook -i environments/distributed/hosts wipe.yml
        ansible-playbook -i environments/distributed/hosts openwhisk.yml
        ansible-playbook -i environments/distributed/hosts postdeploy.yml
12. Now edit the host file for other hosts and repeat the steps 7-8 and 12

this will create the setup in all the nodes. once done, you can use a node balancer to load balance on that. for sync between db instances i m using couchdb continuous replication